# Unexpected errors in oTree

Tags: python, otree

Recently, I have experienced two unexpected errors.

1. I was re-testing my codes for an app. The codes have no errors. However, I started getting error messages for another app which I wasn't testing and which also doesn't have any errors. I am not sure why is this happening, despite there being no errors in my codes. I was just re-testing them before running my experiment. I am attaching a screenshot of the error.
2. Another error that I am experiencing is when I upload my otree zip file on Heroku. Although I have mentioned numpy in the requirements file and as per Chris' suggestion, I removed the line on overwritting, I still keep getting error message in Heroku about numpy.

Can anyone please help me?
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR041.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUnOp.png)

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPXMN.png)

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the parts about (1) including a [mcve] and (2) providing code and error messages as *text*, and **not** *pictures of text* and (3) focusing on a single, specific problem. Also tag your question with the programming language you are using to help find experts that are familiar with the topic area.

Comment: Hi @Quentin, unfortunately, it is not possible for me to reproduce the exact errors as texts.

Comment: Why not? I could do it if I wanted to invest the effort in transcribing it (I don't, I'm not being paid enough to do that). You, OTOH, should be able to copy/paste.

Comment: Hi @Quentin, this is a bit surprising. First of all, you do have the option of attaching images. And secondly, I feel that this site makes things really difficult and not so user friendly for people like me who are struggling with coding and also who have jobs. Not all of us have a lot of time since we are juggling a lot of things at work.

Comment: There are things that are usefully expressed as pictures. Text isn't one of them.

Comment: The mission statement for stackoverflow is "to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming". High quality answers need high quality questions. The mission statement isn't to provide quick solutions for people who don't have the time to frame a good question.

Comment: Hi @Quentin You really don't need to be this humiliating. You are making some assumptions about my intellect without really knowing me. You words are really hurtful.

Comment: I'm making no assumptions about your intellect. I'm just responding to your complaints.